# Android HTTP URLConnection..setConnectTimeout(TIME_OUT);

Tags: android, http, httpurlconnection

I 'm a android newbie, i 'm following this tutorial:http://www.9android.net/android-http-tutorial/. But i don't understand the TIME_OUT value. 
Some one can explain to me and tell me a proper value for TIME_OUT value. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

After 20 seconds the URLConnection will automatically throw a SocketTimeoutException. You specify that in the

```
conection.setConnectTimeout(TIME_OUT);
```

line. 
This means that the system will cancel the connection, which causes your catch block to execute and the connectionTimeout variable will be true.

Comment: oh,many thanks. do you know the proper TIME_OUT value for URLConnection?

Comment: There is no "propper" time out value. It really depends on your app and what you want to do with it. When you expect your request to finish very quick, chose something like 1000 * 20. - That's 20 seconds and a way better approach to write it. 1000 *20 = 1000 milliseconds * 20 = 1 second * 20 = 20 seconds and everybody can read it. You can also do that for minutes, hours and so on (1000 * 60 * 60 * 12 =  12 hours).

Comment: Did I help you? Because getting solutions and not accepting them is frowned upon here.

Answer (score 0):

Time out value is use for

Sets the maximum time in milliseconds to wait while connecting.

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLConnection.html#setConnectTimeout%28int%29

Comment: oh,many thanks. do you know the proper TIME_OUT value for URLConnection?

Answer (score 0):

From the javadoc:

> Sets a specified timeout value, in milliseconds, to be used when opening a communications link to the resource referenced by this URLConnection. If the timeout expires before the connection can be established, a java.net.SocketTimeoutException is raised.

It means that your connection is not established in 20 seconds a SocketTimeoutException will be raised. This may happen because of unstable / not available network.